# Mongodb Inserting an element in a reference array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to insert a User object which has books, and at the same time insert a book. I'm using the following code.

```
db.users.insertOne({
    "_id": new ObjectId(), 
    "username": "testusername",
    "books": [{"_id": new ObjectId(), "name": "Test Book"}]
})
```

Almost works fine, except that the key of my book is just the number 0, or 1 (like in a normal array). **But shouldn't it be the ObjectId (see screenshot).**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are using an array, so that's why key is 0,1,2...
If you want ObjectId to be your key, you have to use an object

```
db.users.insertOne({
    "_id": new ObjectId(), 
    "username": "testusername",
    "books": {
      [new ObjectId()]: { "name": "Test Book" }
    }
})
```

But books will not act like an array anymore, you cannot use any methods of an array. I recommend you to keep using books array.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing `ObjectIds` manually? MongoDB would do that for you ... just:

```
db.users.insertOne({
    "username": "testusername",
    "books": [{"name": "Test Book"}]
})
```

Comment: your method still gives the [0] as key name, instead of the ObjectId, but I now realise maybe that fine. I don't need a name array (aka an object)

Comment: The image you are showing just tells you that in books you have 3 elements. It has nothing to do with the _id of the data stored at those elements. Open each of the elements to see their `_id`

Comment: is it good practice to have named keys for items in a sub-collection? or is the array method ok?

Comment: MongoDB is optimized to do well with both it is more up to you how you want to query/access your data.